# For me it makes sense that $gx \neq x$, but the problem states that $gx=x$, someone help

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Problem

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $X$ be a $G$-set. Assume that $|G|$ does not divide $|X|$. Prove that there exists a $g \in G$ and an $x\in X$ such that $g \neq e$ and such that $gx = x$.
>
> *Hint:* Use Burnside's formula

Solution:

We are given that $|G|$ does not divide $|X|$. This means that $|X|$ cannot be written as a multiple of $|G|$. If $|$Fix$(g)| = |X|$ for all elements $g \in G$, then the number of orbits of $X$ would be equal to $1$, because every element of $X$ would be fixed by every element of $G$. But this would imply that $|X| = |G|$, which is a contradiction. So there must be at least one element $g \in G$ that fixes fewer than $|X|$ elements. This means that there must be at least one element $x \in X$ that is not fixed by $g$, that is, $gx \neq x$. Since $g \neq e$ (the identity element of $G$), this element $x$ satisfies the desired conditions.

Comment: "If |Fix(g)|=|X| for all g in G", then evidently the number of orbits of X would be |X|, each of cardinality 1. In point of fact, this situation is possible for all sets X and for all groups G, the action being $\alpha:G\times X\to X$, $\alpha(g,x)=x$.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: So is my writing wrong or just that I feel it should be written gx ≠ x,

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: For example, use `$\neq$` for $\neq$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are asking, but the question is correct as stated. You need to prove that there exists $g \in G$ and $x \in X$ with $g \ne e$ and $gx=x$.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, let all the pointwise stabilizers be trivial. Then, all the orbits have size $|G|$ (orbit-stabilizer), and hence $|X|$ is a multiple of $|G|$, namely $|G|$ divides $|X|$: contradiction.

---

For a proof by Burnside's (counting) lemma, recall that $\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=$ $\sum_{x\in X}\left|\operatorname{Stab}(x)\right|$, so if all the stabilizers are trivial, then the number of orbits is given by $\frac{|X|}{|G|}$, which is not an integer if $|G|$ does not divide $|X|$. Or, more straighforwardly, note that from the negation of your condition follow $\operatorname{Fix}(e)=X$ and $\operatorname{Fix}(g)=\emptyset$ otherwise, whence back to the previous contradiction.